# How to set weights in Keras with a numpy array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am having trouble with the Keras backend functions for setting values.  I am trying to convert a model from PyTorch to Keras and am trying to set the weights of the Keras model, but the weights do not appear to be getting set.  Note: I am not actually setting with np.ones just using that for an example.

I have tried...

Loading an existing model

```
import keras
from keras.models import load_model, Model
model = load_model(model_dir+file_name)
keras_layer = [layer for layer in model.layers if layer.name=='conv2d_1'][0]
```

Creating a simple model

```
img_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,3,3))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding="valid", 
use_bias=False, name='conv1')(img_input)
model = Model(img_input, x)
keras_layer = [layer for layer in model.layers if layer.name=='conv1'][0]
```

Then using set_weights or set_value

```
keras_layer.set_weights([np.ones((1, 1, 3, 1))])
```

or...

```
K.batch_set_value([(weight,np.ones((1, 1, 3, 1))) for weight in keras_layer.weights])
```

afterwards I call either one of the following:

```
K.batch_get_value([weight for weight in keras_layer.weights])
keras_layer.get_weights()
```

And None of the weights appear to have been set.  The same values as before are returned.

```
[array([[[[  1.61547325e-06],
      [  2.97779252e-06],
      [  1.50160542e-06]]]], dtype=float32)]
```

How do I set the weights of a layer in Keras with a numpy array of values?

Comment: Could you provide your model definition? Also the format of your layers.

Comment: Must have made some other mistake before.  The accepted answer is working for me.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What is `keras_layer` in your code?

You can set weights these ways:

```
model.layers[i].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays)    
model.get_layer(layerName).set_weights(...)
model.set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays)
```

Where `model` is an instance of an existing model. 
You can see the expected length of the list and its array shapes using the method `get_weights()` from the same instances above.

Comment: If you call get_weights again after you set the weights, it returns the original weights and not the values in the list of numpy arrays passed in or are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: When I set weights like this, the method `get_weights()` returns the new weights.

Comment: I am trying to change the datatype of the weights but when I check the datatype of new weight it is just the same as original and not updated.

Comment: @adityathakkar, Why do you need that? I don't think it will work.

Comment: I want to reduce model size so

Comment: You should use `K.set_floatx('float16')`, for instance. Or set it in the `keras.json` file. See details here: https://keras.io/backend/

Comment: Yes I am converting weights using `K.set_floatx('float16')`

Comment: Here is my code snippet. 
`K.set_floatx('float16')
for layer_idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
 old_weights = layer.get_weights()
 for idx, weight in enumerate(old_weights):
  new_weights.append(K.cast_to_floatx(weight))
 model.get_layer(name=layer.name).set_weights(new_weights)`

But this dosen't work

Comment: I never did this, but: you don't need to change anything in the model, only use `K.set_floatx('float16')`, very probably "before" creating the model. If this doesn't work, then go for the `keras.json` file, and start keras again (start your python again). Be careful not to confuse the type in the numpy arrays with the type in the tensors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168927/discussion-between-aditya-thakkar-and-daniel-moller).

Comment: To get the layer name, e.g. on the 25th layer: `model.layers[25].name`

Answer (score 11):

The set_weights() method of keras accepts a list of numpy arrays, what you have passed to the method seems like a single array.
The shape of this should be the same as the shape of the output of get_weights() on the same layer.
Here's the code:

```
l=[]
x=np.array() #weights
y=np.array() #array of biases
l.append(x)
l.append(y)
loaded_model.layers[0].set_weights(l) #loaded_model.layer[0] being the layer
```

This worked for me and it returns the updated weights on calling get_weights().

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to convert Pytorch model to Keras model, you can also try a [Pytorch2Keras](https://github.com/nerox8664/pytorch2keras) converter.

It supports base layers like Conv2d, Linear, Activations, some element-wise operations etc. You can follow `pytorch2keras/layers.py` for layer convertion functions.