# Is it possible to load weight with definite amount or with an initializer in NN in keras in model.add?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, weighted-average

Is it possible to load weight in NN in keras in `model.add`? I want to load the weight based on Xavier or another initializers. How I can do this in keras?

For instance, `weight=[w1,w2,w3,w4]` how we could do this in keras?

For instance, in TF we have: `initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `xxx.h5` is your weights file, do:

```
weights_path = 'path/xxx.h5'
```

You may also load weights in keras like this:

```
model.load_weights(weights_path, by_name=True)
```

Where model is your keras model and its weights architecture match the weights you want to import

Comment: Thanks Alan but I did not understand how I can fill the *.h5 file with for example Xavier initialization! I do not determine the weight by hand to write in *.h5 file, I prefer to use some initializer like Xavier!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load the weights according to a particular initialization using the attribute kernel_initializer for layers

```
model.add(Dense(2,kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))
```

The default value is glorot_uniform

For initializers where you need to provide arguments

```
from keras import initializers

model.add(Dense(64, kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(stddev=0.01))
```

As you mentioned Xavier,in Keras, Xavier uniform and Xavier normal are known as glorot uniform and glorot normal respectively.

Refer to [Keras Initializers](https://keras.io/initializers/) for more initializers

**EDIT:**
If you want to set the weights using a list of numpy arrays, refer to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183159/how-to-set-weights-in-keras-with-a-numpy-array) answer

Comment: Thanks but what I can do if I want to set the weights based on a definite amount. For instance, weight=[w1,w2,w3,w4] how we could do this in keras?