# Keras how to change trainable layers of a loaded model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I built and trained a network based on vgg16 network. In the original network I froze all the layers of vgg16 and trained only the last 4 layers which I added at the end of vgg16. Now I want to load and re-train this model by changing the trainable layers to use my own weights instead of ImageNet weights. Initially I tried to build the same model by changing the trainable layers of vgg16 and model weights with the following code.

```
# Load the VGG model
vgg_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))

# Freeze n number of layers from the last
for layer in vgg_conv.layers[:-8]: layer.trainable = False 

# Check the trainable status of the individual layers
for layer in vgg_conv.layers: print(layer, layer.trainable)          

# Create and compile the model
model = createModel()
trained_model = keras.models.load_model(trained_dir)
model.set_weights(trained_model.get_weights())
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=lr), metrics=['acc'])
```

But this gives me this error:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (3, 3, 3, 64) for Tensor 'Placeholder_869:0', which has shape '(3, 3, 256, 512)'

When I check the weights of the original and new networks I see that shapes of some weights are different. I also tried to change the trainable layers of the original network but `for layer in trained_model.layers: print(layer, layer.trainable)` shows only the last layers that I added. So how can change the trainable layers of my own trained_model? Or is there another way to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183159/how-to-set-weights-in-keras-with-a-numpy-array) might be the possible solution. I created a vgg16 based model with above code. Then I changed weights of the last layers by running this code: `model.layers[1].set_weights(trained_model.layers[1].get_weights())`. Since I added 4 layers to vgg16 I executed this code by changing the layer index from 1 to 4. I have not tried the model yet. If this is not a correct solution I would be glad to read your answers.